# DeprecationWarning: This function is deprecated. See: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#upgrading-to-pyproj-2-from-pyproj-1

Tags: python, pyproj

I am using Jupyter notebook and I have written the following code:

```
#!pip install shapely
import shapely.geometry

#!pip install pyproj
import pyproj
from pyproj import Transformer

import math

def lonlat_to_xy(lon, lat):
    proj_latlon = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong',datum='WGS84')
    proj_xy = pyproj.Proj(proj="utm", zone=33, datum='WGS84')
    xy = pyproj.transform(proj_latlon, proj_xy, lon, lat)
    return xy[0], xy[1]

def xy_to_lonlat(x, y):
    proj_latlon = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong',datum='WGS84')
    proj_xy = pyproj.Proj(proj="utm", zone=33, datum='WGS84')
    lonlat = pyproj.transform(proj_xy, proj_latlon, x, y)
    return lonlat[0], lonlat[1]

def calc_xy_distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1
    return math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)

print('Coordinate transformation check')
print('-------------------------------')
print('Melboourne center longitude={}, latitude={}'.format(loc.longitude, loc.latitude))
x, y = lonlat_to_xy(loc.longitude, loc.latitude)
print('Melboourne center UTM X={}, Y={}'.format(x, y))
lo, la = xy_to_lonlat(x, y)
print('Melboourne center longitude={}, latitude={}'.format(lo, la))
```

// The output is as follows

```
Coordinate transformation check
-------------------------------
Melboourne center longitude=144.9631608, latitude=-37.8142176
Melboourne center UTM X=4980281.116219562, Y=-14408028.424977692
Melboourne center longitude=144.96316080000003, latitude=-37.814217600000006
<ipython-input-3-e6ddd172b39b>:13: DeprecationWarning: This function is deprecated. See: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#upgrading-to-pyproj-2-from-pyproj-1
  xy = pyproj.transform(proj_latlon, proj_xy, lon, lat)
<ipython-input-3-e6ddd172b39b>:19: DeprecationWarning: This function is deprecated. See: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#upgrading-to-pyproj-2-from-pyproj-1
  lonlat = pyproj.transform(proj_xy, proj_latlon, x, y)
```

I can't figure out what changes are required to stop the "DeprecationWarning" message being displayed.

Comment: first you should check link from warning. Maybe it shows what to use instead of deprecated command.

Comment: python has module `warnings` for this - you should find examples how to use it to stop some warnings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this to ignore the warnings:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Comment: It is better to actually follow documentation and fix the DeprecationWarning rather than hiding the problem. If you don't fix the DeprecationWarning, you'll just get an hard error next time you upgrade your dependencies.